# Connection fails when receiving photos from Nintendo Switch

Tags: wi-fi, qr-code, asus-zenfone

I am attempting to [wirelessly send screenshots from my Nintendo Switch](https://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/53138/%7E/how-to-transfer-screenshots-and-video-captures-to-a-smart-device-wirelessly) to my Asus Zenfone 8. However, when I try to scan the QR code to connect to my phone to my Switch I get a "Connection Failed" error. I tried manually connecting to my Switch in the wifi settings and navigating to "http://192.168.0.1/index.html", but the page was stuck on the loading screen in Firefox.

Why can't I transfer photos from my Switch to my Asus Zenfone 8?

[image]
[image]

Comment: You should first check your Wifi router, most routers deny Wifi-to-Wifi connections by default.

Comment: I think this option has the switch emulate a wifi hotspot jtself